# Visual Query Designer in MS SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Is there any Visual Query Designer or builder in MS SQL Server Management Studio 2008 ?

Where is it ?  which menu ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right click in your Query window you will get "**Design Query in Editor**" option.

Comment: Thanks sunil. This works.  Can you please tell how to run query in Query Designer Editor ?

Comment: Once you design a query then Press Ok and  Then execute it.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate, you may create a query by right clicking in the query window to get the "design query in editor" option. If you want to modify the query, highlight the SQL and then right click in the query window and select the "design query in editor." This can only edit the T-SQL that relates to traditional querying (no USE, EXEC, etc)